# Is there a way to read the columns in a shapefile / layer without converting it first to an MDB file?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine

My shapefile has a number of fields, like roadname, and street number.  Is there a way to get at these without converting the shapefile first into a featureclass (mdb)?  Sometimes the conversion is a time consuming operation.

I'm using ArcEngine 10 C# with VS2010

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a shapefile in this context is a feature class just like any other feature class, regardless where it resides, be it folder-based (shapefiles), geodatabase or SDE workspace. There is no need for any conversion.

Just open the shapefile feature class from the workspace and access the [Fields](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Fields_Property/0025000000w0000000/) property on the shapefile table. If you need to query for the actual data, you can use (for example) the [IFeatureClass.Search](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Search_Method/0025000002t9000000/) method.

Answer (score 6):

To just see that other fields without caring about the geometry data, you can just open the dbf-file in any Excel, open office or something else reading dbf-files.

Just be careful not to add or remove any rows, since that will corrupt the shapefile.

/Nicklas

Comment: This got me thinking - one good thing about Excel 2007 not being able to save as DBF anymore is that you cannot corrupt a shapefile with it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you opposed to using open source libraries?  There are quite a few .NET options for dealing with Shapefiles.  I've had very good results with the OGR (C# bindings) and SharpMap.  A quick search on google yields many more options.